# Div moving around on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I am finishing a project which is mainly a photo viewer with a short video at the beginning. Over the video there is a title, something very simple like so:

```
  <div id="presentacion">
    <h1>PARANA</h1>
    <h2>PHOTOGRAPHIES DE MAX RUIZ</h2>
  </div>
```

with a css like so:

```
#presentacion h1{
    font-family: Deser;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: -.2em;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 7.5em;
    letter-spacing: .35em;
    color: white;
}

#presentacion h2{
    font-family: Deser;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: white;
}
```

This looks fine on desktop computers:

http://maxruiz-parana.com

For mobile I have a media queries set up with slightly different css, like so:

```
  #presentacion h1{
    font-family: Deser;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: -.2em;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 9em;
    letter-spacing: .35em;
    color: white;
  }


  #presentacion h2{
    font-family: Deser;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: .2em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    color: white;
  }
```

As you can see, the differences are minimal. Now, if you check the same website on a mobile phone, you will see that the title starts at a completely different place and then snaps into place. 
Why is this happening? Any ideas appreciated. Thanks

EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------------

I found that eliminating the following declaration:

```
html {
  position: fixed;}
```

From my media queries section solved the problem of the title moving, but I do want the html to be fixed for mobile. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to fixed position `html`?

Comment: I don't want the elements to move when you swipe on your mobile, I find it annoying.

Comment: Then it's probably best to fix individual elements like header etc.